# Unable to set Auto Layout constraints for Launch Screen in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints, launch-screen

I am trying to set up a launching screen for my app, but when I add any UI element to the view controller in the launch screen storyboard, I don't see any option for setting constraints like in the main storyboard.

What can be the possible cause?

Comment: You should be able to add constraints to a view without any issue. Usually with Launchscreen.storyboard you can't add any custom code, but auto layout should work fine. If it's not - I would assume there's an issue. It should be just like the main storyboard, with the constraints button down at the bottom right.

Comment: Thank you Eric for your reply. That's what i always done, but this time i can't see the constraints button, not sure what is that!!, i would assume it's related to the localisation as i localised the app and Xcode created files for localisation but i am not sure!

Comment: Oh gosh! I was only missing Use Auto layout!!

Comment: Well - glad you sorted that out! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you missed to check that **checkmark box**.
For those who are facing same issue, following are the steps to **enable Auto layout for Launch screen**:

1) Select the launch screen view controller icon:

[image]

2) Go to the "File Inspector" on right panel:

[image]

3) Check the box saying "Use Auto layout" :

[image]

You'll be now able to set auto layout constraints to launch screen.

Answer (score 1):

Open `LaunchScreen.storyboard`, and in the left pane CTRL+Drag the first components you want to participate to the second component, and use the opened pop-up window:

[image]